# The same instance of an HiveObject cannot be stored with two different keys

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I'm having trouble saving my custom object in the hive DB,

Does hive not support multiple instances of Hive Object??

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer turns out it wasn't a hive issue, I was saving the same instance of the object from the cubit state... solved it by making a copy of the object into a new one :))

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer!